# How many scopes can a openid token contain?

Tags: authentication, architecture, jwt, identityserver4, openid-connect

Well, I haven't find anywhere any guideline about this subject, so here is my case.

I am starting to create a platform of APIs and it's based on JWT tokens generated by an IdentityServer4 server. And I expect to have 75-100 APIs at least.

By trying to follow the specification, I would have to create 75 ApiResource objects and each with a set of scopes (permissions), so we would be talking about 300+ scopes. Defining that into a file although is cumbersome, it is doable.

Now, when we go to the user workflow, the client (web application), in theory, would have to request all the claims any user may need (e.g. 150 scopes), so it is a very large request. And if the user has many roles linked (admin, user, sysadmin), then the token could potentially contain all of those scopes, which is a very large token and that could be problematic.

How would you recommend this be solved? I see several options:

1. Make more use of the user-endpoint with the hit in performance and
   stability. This way the token is smaller but eventually I would
   still need to call the OIDC server to obtain more information about
   the user.
2. Reduce the number of scopes to one per Api, but in the end there could be 75 Apis, so it is still a large number.
3. Reduce the number of scopes to be 1-5 for all Apis, so it is more of a group than a single API. This comes with the reduced effectiveness in the security (or will it really be a management hell to have everything mapped and configured?).

Comment: A scope is not a permission, it's a logical part of the resource. Multiple api's can be part of the same resource and a scope can be implemented in different api's. In other words, hypothetically all those api's could be part of the same resource, requiring only the scopes that define the functionality. A scope is only used to allow the _client_ to contact the _resource_ (on behalf of the user). It's the _user_ that has to be authorized to actually access the resource.

Comment: hmm in IS4, the scopes are divided in identity and in apis. And based on this, you cannot link the same api scope with two resources. At least that is what Is4 has implemented.

Comment: Identity configures the Identity Token. The access token is configured by the Api resource, which is only a logical name, and the scopes which are also logical names. The configuration of the api resource has no relation to the implementation of the api's.

Comment: It's true that the scope name has to be unique, but I don't see how that's relevant to the question. A scope is a logical name for certain functionlity, e.g. calendar. If you want to seperate the availabilty of reading and configuring the calendar, create seperate scopes, e.g. calendar.read and calendar.admin. This doesn't mean that one api has to implement all functionality (though it often does).